# Unable to launch url in chrome using Elementor npm module

Tags: node.js, protractor, elementor

1. Hi All,

   Am using below version of dependencies to run `elementor` on `windows`
   10 console

   ```
   Node : 9.1.0 
   protractor : 5.2.0 
   Elementor : 2.1.0
   ChromeBrowser : 62
   ```

   webdriver-manager is up and running on terminal

   when i type elementor https://www.google.com/

   chrome browser launches but not loading `google.com` url in the
   browser , i tried to downgrade browser version to `61` and tried still
   the same below issue. From console i get below loggers. Please
   suggest how can i get this up and running

   ```
   Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub [15:39:18]
   I/protractor - [15:39:18] I/protractor - ------- Element Explorer
   ------- [15:39:18] I/protractor - Starting WebDriver debugger in a child 
   process. Element Explorer is still beta, please report issues
   at github.com/angular/protractor [15:39:18] I/protractor -
   [15:39:18] I/protractor - Type to see a list of locator strategies.
   [15:39:18] I/protractor - Use the list helper function to find
   elements by strategy: [15:39:18] I/protractor - e.g.,
   list(by.binding('')) gets all bindings. [15:39:18] I/protractor -
   [15:39:18] I/protractor - Debugger exiting
   ```

Comment: I have same issue in node 8.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downgraded node to below version :

node -v
v6.12.0

Elementor, browser.debug(),  browser.pause(), browser.enterRepl()  everything works fine.

Tried node version manager which nvm module to manage more than one versions of node.